# How to make gradual colour change when hover with CSS?

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to make a gradual background colour change from normal to a hover colour, but, unfortunately, everything I've read and tried didn't work. This is the code I have:

```css
.button-submit {
     color: #ffffff;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     line-height: 35px;
     background: #5ea12b;
     padding: 0px 20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     font-size: 18px;
     min-width: 80px;
     min-height: 35px;
     font-family: Light;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     margin: 5px;
}
.button-submit:hover {
     background: #5ea12b;
     color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `transition` property:

EG:

```
.button-submit {
    background: #5ea12b;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

And on hover, change the background color to little darker tone.

```
.button-submit:hover {
     background: #000;
}
```

[**CHECK THE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fm3opm13/1/)

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit better now, but still it's hardly noticeable - I'm trying to make it something like this - http://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-image-hero/ - the red button, in particular. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @nicksss I have updated my answer. Check it and if you think it's right, you can mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's great :) Thanks!